# Data from useEffect not being rendered

Tags: reactjs

I have a function component:

```
// MovieOverview.tsx

const MovieOverview = () => {
  const {data} = useQuery(resolvers.queries.ReturnAllMovies);
  const movie: IMovie = useReactiveVar(moviesVar);

  let movies: IMovie[] = data?.movies;
  let movieRows;

  const setMoviesInRow = (movies: IMovie[]) => {
    const numberOfMovies = Math.floor((window.innerWidth -24) / 185);
    return chunk(movies, numberOfMovies);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    movie ? movies = movies?.concat(movie) : null;
    movies ? movieRows = setMoviesInRow(movies) : null;
    movies ? console.log(movieRows) : null;
  }, [movies, movie]);

  return (
    <div>
      {movieRows?.length}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The `console.log(movieRows)` shows what I expect, an array with some objects. But in the template `movieRows` is undefined.

Comment: is data variable contain data which expected?

Comment: You need to switch to use a Used Tate hook. Make movieRows a useState variable and then put the data variable coming back from useState in the template and then use the setter function that comes out of the useState hook to actually set it in your setMovuesInRow function.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a variable (`movieRows = setMoviesInRow(movies)`) doesn't cause a render, which is why you don't see it. In order to cause a render using React Hooks you must use a "set" function that is returned from the hook (like what is returned from `useState`). This function updates the variable and triggers a render.

For your purpose, `useQuery` doesn't return a "set" function (since you shouldn't need to change the return values of a query). What you should do is use `window.innerWidth` as a state variable that will update with its own `useEffect` - something like [this example](https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/). You might be able to use an existing package like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-hook/window-size) so you don't have to write the hook yourself.

Then you can use it in your component without another `useEffect`:

```
// MovieOverview.tsx

const MovieOverview = () => {
  const windowInnerWidth: Number = useWindowInnerWidth();
  const {data} = useQuery(resolvers.queries.ReturnAllMovies);
  const movie: IMovie = useReactiveVar(moviesVar);

  let movies: IMovie[] = data?.movies;
  let movieRows;
  movie ? movies = movies?.concat(movie) : null;
  const numberOfMovies = Math.floor((windowInnerWidth -24) / 185);
  movies ? movieRows = chunk(movies, numberOfMovies) : null;

  return (
    <div>
      {movieRows?.length}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The component will be re-rendered once when the window is ready and again when the query results arrive.